# Data fetched using Angular from Firebase does not immediately display

Tags: angular, firebase

I am able to fetch the data via Angular that is stored in my Firebase database and display it to a table on my page. The problem is that it is only gets displayed **after** I click on different other parts of my website. How can I get it to immediately display?

My HTML code:

```
    <table class="eduTable table table-striped table-borderless">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>For</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let content of educates">
                <td style="width: 60%">{{content.title}}</td>
                <td>{{content.roles}}</td>
                <td>{{content.updatedAt}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons"
                        style="color: #3DA2DA;">edit</button>
                    <button class="mdc-icon-button material-icons"
                        style="color: #EF4850;">cancel</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

My TypeScript code:

```
export class AdminDashboard implements OnInit {
Form: FormGroup;
educates: Array<any> = [];
educate: Educate;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private educateSrv: EducateService) {
    let res = educateSrv.getAll();
    res.then(result => {
        result.subscribe(async _educates => {
            this.educates = _educates;
            console.log("Initial educate", this.educates);
        });
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.Form = this.fb.group({
        roles: [""],
        type: [""],
        url: [""],
        title: [""]
    });
}

Insert() {
    let _educate = new Educate();
    _educate.roles = this.Form.value.roles;
    _educate.type = this.Form.value.type;
    _educate.url = this.Form.value.url;
    _educate.title = this.Form.value.title;
    _educate.createdBy = this.currentUser;
    _educate.updatedBy = this.currentUser;
    let _date = new Date()
        .toISOString()
        .replace(/T/, " ")
        .replace(/\..+/, "");
    _educate.createdAt = _date;
    _educate.updatedAt = _date;
    this.educateSrv.Insert(_educate);
 }
}
```

Comment: You could simply use [AsyncPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: Why are you using *`Observable` inside `Promise`*? Is it really required?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to add change your loop to use an asyc pipe like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let content of educates | async">
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't know that something new is emitted in the observable especially if you use the OnPush changeDetectionStrategy.

You can tell angular to look for changes whenever something is emitted by your result observable by using the ChangeDetectorRef service : https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef :

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef, ...){}

result.pipe(
     map( _educates => this.educates = _educates)
     tap(() => this.cd.detectChanges())
).subscribe()
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer (changeDetection must indeed be triggered after the value actually changes ! :)